# app-route data not becoming null when pattern is not matched

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Im building this website on Polymer and im having trouble managing going 'back' due to some weird app-route behaviors.

It is a simple website composed of 3 levels of depth and 2 languages (spanish and english). The website shows some architecture projects with their details along with some other sections about the designers, so the route is something like this:

/#/lang/section/ ( for the general navigation ) 
/#/lang/section/projectId( for when viewing project details )

Im using 1 `app-location` and 3 `app-route` in my main app element, like so:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
    <app-route
            route="{{route}}"
            pattern="/:language"
            data="{{languageData}}"
            tail="{{languageSubRoute}}"></app-route>

    <app-route
            route="{{languageSubRoute}}"
            pattern="/:section"
            data="{{sectionData}}"
            tail="{{sectionSubRoute}}"></app-route>

    <app-route
            route="{{sectionSubRoute}}"
            pattern="/:projectName"
            data="{{projectData}}"></app-route>
```

I pass the project id ( when there is one ) to a child view responsible of showing all projects in a grid, and when one is clicked, there is an href change on the main app-location so the changes are propagated down to the view and the project details are show, like so:

```
<projects-view name=" [[_getSectionByLanguage(languageData,'Projects')]]"
                               language="[[languageData.language]]" 
                               displayed-project="[[projectData.projectName]]">
```

I can select a project and display its details with no issues, but when i go 'back' on the route ( /#/en/projects for example ) the `projectData` variable from the third `app-route` doesnt become null and the, so the project details remain visible. However, if i go back and THEN refresh the page, everything works.

I'm observing the uppermost route variable in my main app element, and printing the sub routes as any changes occur.

Output:

```
languageSubRoute: {"prefix":"/en","path":"/projects","__queryParams":{}}
sectionData: {"section":"projects"}
sectionSubRoute: {"prefix":"/en/projects","path":"","__queryParams":{}}
projectData: {"projectName":"Some Project"}
```

So as you can see, even when there is no match for the pattern at the third `app-route`, the data object ( projectData ) doesn't become null

Whats going on ?